# Use Number to get array entry

Tags: python, arrays

So i want to take any integer as an input and get an output based on arrays like this:

Input: 012346

array = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"]

Output: abcdeg

how would i do that?

Comment: Is your input a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a comprehension. Convert input string to a list of characters then get the right element from `array`:

```
inp = '012346'

# For inp to be a string in the case of inp is an integer
out = ''.join([array[int(i)] for i in str(inp)])
print(out)

# Output
abcdeg
```

**Update**

> How i would treat numbers above 10 since they would get broken down to 1 and 0

Suppose the following input:

```
inp = '1,10,2,3'
array = list('abcdefghijklmn')

out = ''.join([array[int(i)] for i in inp.split(',')])
print(out)

# Output
'bkcd'
```

Comment: So your input is a number or a string. Convert `inp` to string

Comment: on thing i am wondering is just how i would treat numbers above 10 since they would get broken down to 1 and 0

Comment: If you want numbers greater than 10, you have to change your input format.

Comment: @Titus. I updated my answer. Can you check it please?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) could do the job.

```py
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> itemgetter(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6)(array)
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'g')
```

Answer (score 0):

The `input` function in Python always returns a string, unless you cast it into another type. So you can loop over the digits of this string, cast the digits individually into an integer, and use that to fetch the letters from the list and concatenate them:

```
str = “”
data = input(“Data? “)
for digit in data:
    str += array[int(digit)]
```